# Java guessingGame errors

Tags: java, exception

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class GuessingGame {

    public static void main(String[]args) throws BadGuessException
    {
        int min = 1;
        int max = 10;
        Random rand = new Random();

        int numberToGuess = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;    

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int guess;
        boolean win = false; 
        int numberOfTries = 0;

        while (!win) 
        {

            System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 10: ");
            try
            {
                guess = input.nextInt();
                numberOfTries++;

                win=true;

                if (guess == numberToGuess)
                {       
                    win = true;
                    System.out.println("YOU GOT IT!");
                    System.out.println("It took you " + numberOfTries + " tires.");

                }
                else
                {
                    throw new BadGuessException();
                }
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Please input a number betwee 1 and 10!");
            }
            catch(BadGuessException ex) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, you guessed the wrong number!");
            }
        }
    }
}
class BadGuessException extends Exception {

    private static final String message = "Sorry, that was an invalid guess!";

    public BadGuessException() {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Here is the prompt:
Create an Exception class called BadGuessException

BadGuessException should be a sub-class of the Exception class [1 point]
Create 2 constructors [1 point]
A default constructor in the BadGuessException class, that passes the message "Sorry, that was an invalid guess!" to the parent constructor using keyword super.
A parameterized constructor in the BadGuessException class that will pass the parameter to the parent constructor using keyword super.
Create a class called GuessingGame

Generate a random number between 1 and 10.
Prompt the user to guess the number. Allow the user unlimited attempts to guess the number correctly. [1 point]
Once the user guesses the number correctly, print out "YOU GOT IT!" and print out how many tries it took the user to guess the number. [1 point]
Using a try-catch block, add exception handling to your code.
try-catch block proper syntax [1 point]
throw a BadGuessException if the user enters any number that is not between 1 and 10.  [1 point]
Add another catch block to catch the exception thrown if the user enters an incorrect format for number they guessed, such as "five" or "5.0". This should prevent your program from crashing or throwing a run time excpetion.  When this exception is caught, the program should not crash and should display "Sorry, you entered an invalid number format". [1 point]

Now i have the code running but it keeps running a loop in the compiler when.

Comment: Please try to first use the debugger, and if you could update your post with a more thorough description of where and how the problem is occurring, that would help.

Comment: The error i am having with the code is for this section: Add another catch block to catch the exception thrown if the user enters an incorrect format for number they guessed, such as "five" or "5.0". This should prevent your program from crashing or throwing a run time excpetion. When this exception is caught, the program should not crash and should display "Sorry, you entered an invalid number format"

Comment: And whenever i enter or input an invalid response when i run the code it keeps looping this:Guess a number between 1 and 10: 
Please input a number between 1 and 10!

Comment: The problem im getting is whenever i do enter an invalid type it should give me this message: Sorry, you entered an invalid number Format!" instead it keeps looping this message : Guess a number between 1 and 10: 
Please input a number betwee 1 and 10!

Comment: I did some testing. Try changing ```guess = input.nextInt();``` to ```guess = Integer.parseInt(input.next())``` and catch the thrown ```NumberFormatException``` instead.

Comment: that fixes the loop issue i just want it whenever i enter an invlid number type like say i input two instead of the number 2 that it relays me this message:Sorry, you entered an invalid number Format! I can't seem to get that D:

Comment: So instead of printing ```"Please input a number betwee 1 and 10!"``` just print that.

Comment: lol xD is that what my issue was the whole time btw just double checking there weren't any other errors that you saw?

Comment: @jaegers1234 Well, I changed a few things on my own for fun, but no more errors. If I had to give a tip; Put the code to take 1 guess in a separate function, it makes the whole thing more readable.

Comment: i'm still quite new to the exceptions what use is this in the code? {class BadGuessException extends Exception {

    private static final String message = "Sorry, that was an invalid guess!";

    public BadGuessException() {
        super(message);
    }
}

Comment: It makes it so that you don't have to pass the message every time you throw the exception. i.e. ```throw new Exception("Message");```. And it's a ```static final String``` to indicate a _compile time constant_.

Comment: You are a life saver John xD thank you very much for the help i appreciate it from the catacombs of my heart man.

Comment: Well i found another problem with the code xD it won't let me an unlimited amount of tries the code should allow this: Prompt the user to guess the number. Allow the user unlimited attempts to guess the number correctly. [1 point]
Once the user guesses the number correctly, print out "YOU GOT IT!" and print out how many tries it took the user to guess the number. [1 point]

Comment: I want it to let me try as many times as i want until i get it right

Answer (score -1, accepted):

public class GuessingGame {

```
private static Scanner input;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int numbertoguess = rand.nextInt(10);
    int numberoftries =0;
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int guess;
    boolean win = false;

    while(win == false)
    {
        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 10");
        try
        {
        guess = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        numberoftries++;

        if (guess == numbertoguess)
        {       
            win = true;
            System.out.println("That is correct !!");
            System.out.println("The number is : " + numbertoguess + " and it took you " + numberoftries + " tries");

        }
        else  
        {
            throw new BadGuessException();
        }
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry, you entered an invalid number Format!");
    }
    catch(BadGuessException ex) 
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry, you guessed the wrong number!  ");
    }
}
```

}
}

Comment: It still won't repeat ;-;

Comment: my coding is a little different than yours but i still got the same results I will the code

Comment: Thank you so much it works if you don't mind can you tell me what you changed and what i was doing wrong as it'd be helpful for me to know for future endeavors.